# Domain of a function with two variables

Tags: calculus

$f(x,y)=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2-1)(4-x^2-y^2)}$. I know that I need $(x^2+y^2-1)(4-x^2-y^2)\ge0 \Leftrightarrow (x^2+y^2-1)(x^2+y^2-4)\le0$. Could you please help me to continue? This is first time for me to find domain of function with two variables.

Comment: Are we restricted only is $ \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: I think $\mathbb{R}^n$ even though its not specified in my problem

Comment: He means, I believe, are you restricted to $x$ and $y$ being real numbers - which is typically the case. You are correct that $(x,y)$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ if $x,y$ are real.

Comment: I am sorry, yes you are right izoec, we are indeed restricted to real numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if $x^2 + y^2 = 1,4$, then the inequality is satisfied directly. These have nice interpretations as being the points on a circle of radii 1 and 2 respectively. If $1< x^2 + y^2 < 4$ then the inequality is also satisfied, as 
$$
(x^2+y^2-1)(x^2+y^2-4)
$$
is a product of a positive and negative term. It is not to difficult to see that if $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ or $x^2 + y^2 > 4$, the product will always be positive - hence, the domain is the set of $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ where $1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$.

Comment: I didn't realize it is actually a equation of a circle, thank you for pointing that out.PS: is correct to write that the domain is $D_{f}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2,1\le x^2+y^2 \le 4\}$?

Comment: @cryogenic Each of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ conditions in the inequality for the domain give bounding circles on the domain of your function $f$. And yes, your $D_f$ looks to be the correct notation.

Answer (score 1):

If $ x, y \in \mathbb{R} $ then, we have

$$ x^2 + y^2 \ge 0 \tag{ $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ } $$

Therefore, for $ (x^2 + y^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2 - 4) \le 0 $ will give you:

$ \color{red}{(x^2 + y^2 - 1) \ge 0} $ and $ \color{red}{(x^2 + y^2 - 4) \le 0} $ which is $$ 1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 4 $$ or the area between concentric circles with centre at origin and radii $ 1$ and $ 2 $ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=x^2+y^2.$ Then you need either $(u-1) \ge 0$ and $4-u \ge 0$, which gives $1 \le u \le 4$, or else you need $u-1 \le 0$ and $4-u \ge 0$, i.e. the impossible combination $u<1$ and $u>4.$

So it's the first possibility, i.e. $1 \le u \le 4$ which is the region between the two concentric circles of radii $1$ and $2$, and includes both bounding circles.